# ng-show directive not working Angular (controllerAs issue)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, callback, angular-promise, ng-show

I am building a single-page app with a timer and 2 buttons:

- 1st one shows up on initial state (onBreak=false), and handles a 25min-timer
- 2nd one shows up when the 1st timer is over (onBreak=true), and handles a 5min-timer

Here is the HTML :

```
  <h1>{{ home.time | formattime }}</h1>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-hide="onBreak"
          ng-click="home.workTimer()" ng-bind="home.startOrResetWork">
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="onBreak"
          ng-click="home.breakTimer()" ng-bind="home.startOrResetBreak">
  </button>
```

The controller :

```
(function() {
  function HomeCtrl($interval) {
    var $ctrl = this;

    var promise;

    $ctrl.time = 1500;
    $ctrl.startOrResetWork = "START WORK";
    $ctrl.startOrResetBreak = "START BREAK";

    $ctrl.onBreak = false;

    $ctrl.stopTimer = function() {
      $interval.cancel(promise);
    };

    $ctrl.startTimer = function() {
      promise = $interval(function() {$ctrl.time--;}, 1000, [$ctrl.time]);
    };

    $ctrl.workTimer = function() {
      ($ctrl.startOrResetWork === "START WORK") ? $ctrl.startOrResetWork = "RESET" : $ctrl.startOrResetWork = "START WORK";
      if ($ctrl.startOrResetWork === "START WORK") {
        $ctrl.stopTimer();
        $ctrl.time = 1500;
      } else if ($ctrl.startOrResetWork === "RESET") {
        $ctrl.startTimer();
        promise.then(function() {
                      $scope.onBreak = true;
                    });
      }
    };

    $ctrl.breakTimer = function() {};

  }

  angular
    .module('pomodoroManager')
    .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$interval', HomeCtrl]);
})();
```

And app.js

```
(function() {

  function config($locationProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $locationProvider
      .html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
      });

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl as home',
        templateUrl: '/templates/home.html'
    });
  }

  angular
    .module('pomodoroManager', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'firebase'])
    .config(config);
})();
```

Basically, once the first countdown is over (promise.then(...)), I set onBreak to true, which should display the second button using the ng-show directive.

THE PROBLEM?
It does not. Using ng-inspector, I see that onBreak does equal true, but I keep seeing the first button and not the second one.

OTHER ISSUE:
Let say I create a function:

```
$ctrl.toggleOnBreak = function() {
  $ctrl.onBreak = true;
};
```

An then do:

```
promise.then($ctrl.toggleOnBreak());
```

I still don't get the correct button behavior, and even worse, onBreak get set to true on click, instead of when the timer is over...

Help please... it has been too long I am stuck on that

Comment: onBreak is a field of $ctrl. But the HTML uses `onBreak`, and thus expects the field to be on the $scope.

Comment: Alright. I am relatively new to Angular, and I am not sure how to use $scope; when I pass it in the controller function, I get a TypeError: $interval is not a function...

Comment: Edit the question to include the HTML where you instantiate the controller. It is confusing to the readers to use `$ctrl` in the JS and `home` in the HTML.

Comment: Done! Did it in app.js though. Probably not the best way? I am still learning Angular...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using `controllerAs` syntax in the controller but not in the HTML`. in your html need to reference a property to access the values.

```
ng-controller="HomeCtrl as $ctrl"
```

Now access the variable like this.

```
ng-hide="$ctrl.onBreak"
```